# Jaxb does not valid unmarschall after upgradeing java and springboot

Tags: java, kotlin, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the same code in `kotlin`:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.StringReader
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*


val jaxbContext: JAXBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response::class.java)
val jaxbUnmarshaller: Unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller()


@XmlRootElement(name = "xml")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class Response(@XmlElement(name = "data", namespace = "rs") val data: Data? = null)
data class Data(@field:XmlElement(name = "Row") val row: MutableList<Row>? = null)
data class Row(@XmlAttribute val error: String? = null)
```

The method for unmarschalling

```
fun umarshallAsSimpleResponse(xmlString: String): Response {
    val reader = StringReader(xmlString)
    return jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader) as Response
}
```

The input (`xmlString`) is the same as before:

```
  <xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3FO-6DA3-1ldl-A2A3-00AA00C14882' xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-6583-1ldl-429F-OOAAOOC14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' xmlns:z='#Rowsetschema'>
    <rs:data>
        <Row error="0" Usl=" " Data=" " Przedz=" " Cena=" " Ilosc="0" Konto=" "
        errorMessage="Status został zmieniony."></Row>
    </rs:data>
  </xml>
```

But before upgrading to java 17 and newer SpringBoot
the result was:

```
Data(row=[Row(error=0)])
```

Now the result is:

```
Response(data=null)
```

What changed is jaxb library in `gradle`:

before it was: `com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11-xsd-doc-0.2.0`
now to make it work with java-17 it is: `org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.7/`

How can I make it work with the new library ?
I think that this functionality has to work with new library as well as the old one. It's pretty standard functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues going from the same version of Jaxb. See [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76483771/jaxb-error-when-unmarshalling-apache-cxf-soap-response-after-upgrading-from-vers)

I found my solution was a namespace issue, 2.2.11 is less strict and newer versions of java, spring are all above that.

It seems you aren't setting the correct namespace, `Response` is expecting a `Data` element with namespace `rs` but you're feeding it `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset` in the sample.

Try changing:

`class Response(@XmlElement(name = "data", namespace = "rs") val data: Data? = null)`

To:

`class Response(@XmlElement(name = "data", namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset") val data: Data? = null)`

Comment: I have tried it but it did not help.
I have changed logic in code to retrun "errorValue"

   `val factory: DocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()`

    ```val builder: DocumentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder()

    val document: Document = builder.parse(InputSource(StringReader(xmlString)))

    val rootElement: Element = document.documentElement

    val errorValue: String? =

        rootElement.firstChild.firstChild.attributes.getNamedItem("error").nodeValue;
    return errorValue```